# Forked and executed program does not returns to console

Tags: c++, console, exec, fork

I took example program from [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/listings/chapter-3/fork-exec.c) site:

```
/***********************************************************************
* Code listing from "Advanced Linux Programming," by CodeSourcery LLC  *
* Copyright (C) 2001 by New Riders Publishing                          *
* See COPYRIGHT for license information.                               *
***********************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Spawn a child process running a new program.  PROGRAM is the name
   of the program to run; the path will be searched for this program.
   ARG_LIST is a NULL-terminated list of character strings to be
   passed as the program's argument list.  Returns the process id of
   the spawned process.  */

int spawn (char* program, char** arg_list)
{
  pid_t child_pid;

  /* Duplicate this process.  */
  child_pid = fork ();
  if (child_pid != 0)
    /* This is the parent process.  */
    return child_pid;
  else {
    /* Now execute PROGRAM, searching for it in the path.  */
    execvp (program, arg_list);
    /* The execvp function returns only if an error occurs.  */
    fprintf (stderr, "an error occurred in execvp\n");
    abort ();
  }
}

int main ()
{
  /* The argument list to pass to the "ls" command.  */
  char* arg_list[] = {
    "ls",     /* argv[0], the name of the program.  */
    "-l", 
    "/",
    NULL      /* The argument list must end with a NULL.  */
  };

  /* Spawn a child process running the "ls" command.  Ignore the
     returned child process id.  */
  spawn ("ls", arg_list); 

  printf ("done with main program\n");

  return 0;
}
```

After compiling and running it from the console, the child process does not exit, thus it doesn't release the console.

Only Ctrl+C helps to return to console.

```
vladon@vladon-dev-mint64 ~/Projects/test $ gcc -o test test.c
vladon@vladon-dev-mint64 ~/Projects/test $ ./test
done with main program
vladon@vladon-dev-mint64 ~/Projects/test $ total 104
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 11 11:57 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Mar 11 11:57 boot
[ ... too many lines of my filesystem skipped ... ]
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Nov 27 01:12 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Nov 27 01:48 var
^C
vladon@vladon-dev-mint64 ~/Projects/test $
```

How can I run another program and exit to console back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first program completed, without waiting for the child process to complete.  The shell gave you a prompt, but then the output of the `ls -l` command started.

The shell was still waiting for you when you hit the interrupt; if you'd typed `echo Hi`, it would have done your bidding.

Here's your sample output, annotated:

```
vladon@vladon-dev-mint64 ~/Projects/test $ gcc -o test test.c
vladon@vladon-dev-mint64 ~/Projects/test $ ./test
done with main program
vladon@vladon-dev-mint64 ~/Projects/test $ total 104
```

The previous line has your prompt, and also the first line of output from `ls -l`.

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 11 11:57 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Mar 11 11:57 boot
[ ... too many lines of my filesystem skipped ... ]
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Nov 27 01:12 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Nov 27 01:48 var
^C
```

If you'd typed `echo Hi` instead of <kbd>Control-C</kbd>, you'd have seen `Hi` and the next prompt.  Just like you got the next prompt after interrupting the shell…

```
vladon@vladon-dev-mint64 ~/Projects/test $
```